# using cancan getting undefined local variable or method `roles'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I've given up on trying to lock down every action in the application. Currently I'm placing in every controller except the devise/registration:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

in the user model:

```
  def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
  end
```

in the ability model:

```
if user.role? :superadmin
  can :manage, :all
end
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `roles'
app/models/user.rb:33:in `role?'
app/models/ability.rb:7:in `initialize'
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Because of Bohdan's answer below i looked further into the documentation and found there are differing methods of setting up the cancan model(s). currently we have 6 different roles resulting in 6 different Boolean fields in the database. I was thinking of a hierarchical approach to defining roles where one user could have many roles and one role has many users. There are two ways to set up the role definitions. [First](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization). [Second](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model). For ease of use i think i'll define each role exhaustively so there is only one role for each person. Wondering what the disadvantages of that are.

UPDATE: I commented out all the other roles other than superadmin as defined above. Realized that it doesn't have anything to do with many to many issue. So...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` in your model or any other custom definition for method `roles`

**Edit**

after you added `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` to your `User` model to make everything work you need

define new model called `Role` with at least `name` attribute

change

```
def role?(role)
  roles.include? role.to_s
end
```

to

```
def role?(role)
  roles.map(&:name).include? role.to_s
end
```

**Edit**

migration

```
class CreateRolesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles_users do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :role_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

just add this migration and run `rake db:migrate` rails will do the rest

Comment: Thanks. I placed that in the user model and still got, "uninitialized constant User::Role". I haven't found anything in the documentation about adding "has_many :roles."

Comment: Nope... the model i am using is called ability.rb which sets up the class, but not a class as "< ActiveRecord::Base". (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) +1 for hanging in with me on this.

Comment: Now i am getting "Table 'database_name.roles_users' doesn't exist. ugh!

Comment: I removed "< ActiveRecord::Base" from the Role model and now i am getting, "undefined method `quoted_table_name' for Role:Class". Going back to the documentation to read again. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Bohdan. Thanks for all your input. Another +1 for hanging with me. I've decided to bag using the multiple roles approach. Banged my head against that wall enough. Going to the single role approach even tho it isn't as flexible. Again... thanks for your help.

Comment: well you're the boss) however I strongly recommend you check http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/videos/047-two-many-to-many.mp4 first well if you have seen it I suppose you have your own reasons to use other approach so I wish you good luck

Answer (score 0):

rails HBTM relations order the table name alphabetically. Try changing your migration to

```
create_table :user_roles
```